# Difference between self.navigationController.view and self.view in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

About difference between `self.navigationController.view` and `self.view in UITableViewController`, as far as i know is:

1. self.view is smaller than `self.navigationController.view` (44 px)
2. self.view is used to execute `loadView()` or load from nib file.

However, i'm thinking i'm still at the very beginning of understanding `UITableViewController`

Is there anybody could explain more? For example I can not understand below:

1. correct:`[_packListPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) inView:self.navigationController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];`
2. wrong: `[_packListPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

`self.navigationController` returns the navigation controller that the controller (self) is embedded in. In other words, a navigation controller has a child/ancestor controller within it that is your `UITableViewController`. I recommend reading Apple's documentation on View Controllers to get a basic understanding of View Controller hierarchies.

While the `UITableViewController` is embedded in the Navigation Controller, this does not prevent its size property from being larger. The frame property of a view is used to set its size if you want to change it.

[View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)